# $f(x^{-1})$ = $\left(f(x)\right)^{-1}$. Does this property have a name?

Tags: functions, inverse

A question asked today made me think of this case :

$f(x^{-1})$ = $\left(f(x)\right)^{-1}$.

Apparently the function ($x^2$) , for example, satisfies this condition. So does the absolute value function. Maybe I should ask whether there is some function that does not have this property.

Is this property of any interest and has it received a name?

The formula reminds me of the definition of " isomorphism" ( " the image of the product is the product of the images"). Is this purly accidental?

Here the " operation" would be unary and would be " inversion".

Comment: Perhaps [even function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions)? It's stretching the term, of course.

Comment: This property is also true for any homomorphism, say between two groups. I don't know of any name though.

Comment: It's the multiplicative analog of an even function.  If you take $g(x) = \log(f(\exp(x))$ then $g(-x) = -g(x)$.

Comment: You could also say that such functions $f$ are those which commute (under composition) with the function $g(x) = 1/x$. All power functions $f(x) = x^a$ have this property along with their negations $-x^a$ and some piecewise combinations of them such as $|x|$. Probably many others too but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JairTaylor: "$g(-x) = -g(x)$" - apparently you (and Calum Gilhooley) are using the term "even function" in a new and unusual way in which I have never heard it used before.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, sorry. odd function of course.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That was incredibly careless of me. I'm sorry.

Comment: So, here, $(f(x))^{-1}$ definitely means the multiplicative inverse of $f(x)$, right? Not $y\to x$ where $f$ is $x\to y$, am I correct?

Comment: That's it : it is the reciprocal ( multiplicative inverse) of $f(x)$

Comment: Not the inverse function ( namely $f^{-1}(x)$), that is, as you noted, the function that " undoes" what function $f$ has done.